# how to pass char pointer as argument in ctypes python

Tags: python, char, ctypes

Please help me in converting below line of c++ code into ctypes python:

```
Ret = openFcn(&Handle, "C:\\Config.xml");
```

below are the declarations of each:

```
typedef uint16_t (* OpenDLLFcnP)(void **, const char *);
OpenDLLFcnP openFcn = NULL;
openFcn = (OpenDLLFcnP) myLibrary.resolve("Open");
void *Handle = NULL;
```

Comment: so many downvotes and no helpful explanation of why...

Comment: however, I'm guessing it's because it seems like you're just trying to have others do some coding work for you; you might be better off taking some time to learn ctypes, and if you still can't handle it on your own, you can come back here, perhaps with a more concrete question.

Comment: It's a valid question.  OP should give more background.  I upvoted to counter,.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myLibrary.resolve` is undefined, but the general code you need (untested) is:

```
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.CDLL('your.dll')
Open = dll.Open
Open.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p),ctypes.c_char_p]
Open.restype = ctypes.c_uint16
Handle = ctypes.c_void_p()
result = Open(ctypes.byref(Handle),'c:\\Config.xml')
```

This assumes you have a DLL named `your.dll` with a function `Open` you want to call.

Comment: thanks a ton.....i was using byref(handle) instead of ctypes.byref(handle).......

Comment: You're welcome...if this post answered your question, you can accept it as the answer to clicking the check next to the post.