# "char *pList" in ctypes

Tags: c++, string, python-3.x, pointers, ctypes

I am trying to use ctypes to control an instrument (a camera). I want to know what I should do in ctypes if the C function I am calling expect `char *pList` as argument. The documentation in the .h header file is:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// Opening the camera
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /// Enumerates all available devices. Device names are separated by a pipe '|' symbol.
        /// @param pList zero terminated string which will receive the device list
        /// @param iMaxLen allocated memory available for the device list
        /// @return A device list containing 'connectionurl'|'description' .. 
        static void IMPEXP GetDeviceList(char *pList, int iMaxLen);
```

I tried something like:

```
data = ctypes.c_char_p(64)
lib.XC_GetDeviceList(ctypes.pointer(data),64)
```

But it doesn't seem to execute properly (return value is not zero). What is the correct input argument I need to supply?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959220/how-to-pass-char-pointer-as-argument-in-ctypes-python) help?

Comment: @user202729 I've read that example, but I'm still quite confused. Correct me if I'm wrong. `ctypes.c_char_p()` is a pointer, and the C function I'm calling wants a pointer that points to a string, so I just need to pass `ctypes.c_char_p()` as argument without the `ctypes.pointer()`? But if I just try to execute `XC_GetDeviceList(data,64)`, then it gives `OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000400`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create_string_buffer` creates a buffer that the DLL can write to.  use `.value` and `.raw` to access the contents:

```
>>> data = ctypes.create_string_buffer(5)
>>> data
<ctypes.c_char_Array_5 object at 0x000001D142F2D948>
>>> data.raw
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> data.value
b''
```

`.raw` lists all the bytes in the buffer.

`.value` returns the data up to the terminating null.

Here's an example:

```
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('camera') # Use your DLL name

# Not always required, but allows ctypes to better error check the call.
dll.GetDeviceList.argtypes = c_char_p,c_int  # argument types
dll.GetDeviceList.restype = None             # return type

pList = create_string_buffer(1000) # Create a writable char* buffer.
dll.GetDeviceList(pList,len(pList))
print(pList.value) # Your documentation says null-terminated data is returned.
```